# @ sign in SailsJS comments

Tags: sails.js, comments

Consider automatically generated comments at the begining of a model:

```
/**
 * User.js
 *
 * @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */
```

What does @ sign state for in `@description` and `@docs` lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think the @ just represents an entity. See [JSdoc standard](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html)

Comment: Ok, and as I see apiDoc documentation compiler uses same syntax. But by default SalsJS come with no documentation framework. Is it some universal agreement?

Comment: pretty much-- def not universal, just relatively common, even across languages.  By no means the only right way :)